# Почему я получаю пустой запрос?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Использую в своих проектах на стороне клиента vue.js, а сервера - node+express

Код POST-запроса выглядит так:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {Router} = require('express');
const router = Router();


let jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

router.post('/', jsonParser,(req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json('Hi')
});

module.exports = router;
```

Используя POSTMAN или rested запрос приходит успешно, req.body отображается корректно.
Однако, если отправляю запрос со стороны своего клиента получаю в ответ пустое тело.

```js
addCar: async function (titleOfCar) {
                if (titleOfCar.length === 0) {
                    alert('Введите, пожалуйста, модель автомобиля');
                } else {
                    try {
                        await fetch(this.url, {
                            method: 'POST',
                            mode: 'no-cors',
                            body: JSON.stringify(new Car(this.adminCars.length + 1, titleOfCar, [new Work('', 0)])),
                            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
                        })
                            .then(res => {
                                res.json();
                            })
                            .then(data => {
                                this.selectedCar = data
                            })
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error('Ошибка:', e.message);
                    }
                    await this.load();
                }
            }
```

В чем может быть моя ошибка?

Comment: сравни какой запрос уходит когда делаешь через postman и какой через vue

Comment: @Grundy Параметры запросов одинаковые, за исключением того, что с клиента в параметрах запроса указан mode: no-cors

Comment: а так, везде Content-Type: application/json

Comment: `res.ok` `true`?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov Да

Comment: `.then(res => {  res.json(); })`  ты не возвращаешь результат. Ну и попробуй без `no-cors`

Comment: @Grundy Без CORS появляется ошибка CORS Policy, а результат у меня возвращается в присваивании  .then(data => {
                                this.selectedCar = data

Comment: @Grundy Для исправления ошибки CORS Policy res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"); пробовал это указать в post-методе, но ошибка не уходит

Comment: без cors просто шли с того же домена.

Comment: _результат у меня возвращается в присваивании .then(data => { this.selectedCar = data_ - если ты ничего не возвращаешь на предыдущем шаге - то data у тебя будет undefined

Comment: @Grundy Пустое тело запроса я получаю на стороне сервера. Так как в консоли я прошу вывести req.body и получаю {} Я попробую сначала устранить проблему с CORS policy. При проверке работы метода с помощью json-server все работает корректно. Но я попробую все ответы которые мне тут дали

Comment: @Grundy Просто идея как раз заключается в том, чтобы и сервер и клиент были отдельными проектами и не находились на одном домене. Но за все Ваши ответы душевно благодарю

Comment: @ПавелПетров, ты сначала проверь, если при запросе с одного домена у тебя все начинает приходить - значит просто сделай настройки корса на сервере, чтобы он всем разрешал.

Comment: Обрати внимание, что у тебя на сервере только для post обработчик, а за разрешениями шлется OPTIONS

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо большое за помощь, решил проблему с cors - ситуация с запросами решилась соответственно

Comment: @ПавелПетров, добавь свой ответ, в чем была проблема, и что сделал, чтобы ее решить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У данной ситуации причиной послужило то, что на стороне клиента запросы отправлялись с установленным `mode: 'no-cors'`. Данный кусочек был удален, на стороне сервера установил пакет cors, который устраняет проблему с CORS policy. Настраивал middleware согласно документации: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Answer (score 0):

Измените

```
  .then(res => {
                  res.json();
       })
```

На

```
       .then(res => {
                  return res.json();
       })
```

Либо на

```
    .then(res => res.json())
```

Comment: Да, попробую. Я наверное сам некорректно задал вопрос.У меня в консоли сервера эта команда console.log(req.body); Выдает тело запроса. Выдает она: {} и больше ничего